# InvalidOperationException while formatting date

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to format my date using .ToString() but I keep getting this error, I understand where it's coming from but I have no idea how to fix it.

The error message I keep getting is: **InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.**

Currently my code inside my view looks like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DatePrescribed.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss"))
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PatientDiagnosis.PatientDiagnosisId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Treatment.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.PatientTreatmentId">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.PatientTreatmentId">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.PatientTreatmentId">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
```

The line in question is:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DatePrescribed.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss"))
```

I've been stuck on this for a while so any solution would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Decorate your property with [DisplayFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) like below:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss}")]
public DateTime DatePrescribed { get; set; }
```

And then simply in your view just call property:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DatePrescribed)
```

Comment: Hey I've tried your solution but now I am getting a formatexception where my input string is not in the right format?  in the same line which is the same as yours.  In my index: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DatePrescribed) and the only thing I've changed is adding the property: [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss}")]
        public DateTime DatePrescribed { get; set; }

Comment: @SamF The format is correct. But to be sure, try the updated answer and test it. What is the value you're assigning to `DatePrescribed`? Are you reading it from db or something?